# Example of commutative Hopf algebra over the integers

Tags: commutative-algebra, hopf-algebras, group-schemes

I'm looking for an example of a commutative Hopf algebra $H$ such that

- $H$ is a torsion free $\mathbb{Z}$ module of finite rank
- $H$ is not isomorphic to the dual of a group algebra $\mathbb{Z}G$
- $H \neq \mathbb{Z}$

By commutative I mean commutative in the strict sense (i.e. xy = yx) and not in the graded sense.

I have been googling a lot, but couldn't find an example.

Comment: I think the first condition implies that the spectrum is a finite etale group scheme, which means I think there are no examples because the etale fundamental group is trivial.